# Autofac DI error in WebApi2 with OWIN

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

I have problem with DI in WebApi. I have add autofac accordingly with the [instruction](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html). But something is wrong with resolving controller.

I get an error:

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ValuesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
"InnerException": {
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Type 'WebApiOwinAutoFac.Controllers.ValuesController' does not have a default constructor",
"ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
   }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // STANDARD WEB API SETUP:

        // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
        // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<TestRepository>().As<ITestRepository>();

        // Run other optional steps, like registering filters,
        // per-controller-type services, etc., then set the dependency resolver
        // to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // OWIN WEB API SETUP:

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

ValuesController.cs

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private ITestRepository _context { get; set; }

    public ValuesController(ITestRepository context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetTest()
    {
        var testList = _context.GetAll();
        return String.Join(",", testList.Select(s => s.Name));
    }
}
```

ITestRepository.cs

```
public interface ITestRepository
{
    IEnumerable<TestModel> GetAll();
}
```

TestRepository.cs

```
public class TestRepository : ITestRepository
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<TestModel> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Tests;
    }
}
```

My sample project where I try to make it works, is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/samuelwig/WebApiAutofac):
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You omitted the all-important `Global.asax` code from your question... which actually is what points to the answer: That you've not fully converted to OWIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your sample project isn't using OWIN. It's still using classic non-OWIN ASP.NET Web API. If you [look at your Global.asax.cs](https://github.com/samuelwig/WebApiAutofac/blob/master/WebApiOwinAutoFac/Global.asax.cs#L17) you'll see that you're still using `GlobalConfiguration`. You can't use `GlobalConfiguration` when using OWIN.

You will notice in [the Autofac docs on Web API and OWIN integration](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration) the following:

> A common error in OWIN integration is use of the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`. **In OWIN you create the configuration from scratch.** You should not reference `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` anywhere when using the OWIN integration.

Remove the usage of `GlobalConfiguration` from your Global.asax and switch entirely to OWIN. You can't mix and match or you will run into trouble like this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Travis Illig. I also learn new thing today.

You need two things - remove GlobalConfiguration inside Global.ascx.cs, and register Web API route using OWIN.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApiOwinAutoFac.Startup))]
namespace WebApiOwinAutoFac
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // STANDARD WEB API SETUP:

            // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
            // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Register your Web API controllers.
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<TestRepository>().As<ITestRepository>();

            // Run other optional steps, like registering filters,
            // per-controller-type services, etc., then set the dependency resolver
            // to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            // OWIN WEB API SETUP:

            // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
            // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

### Global.ascx.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); <-- Delete this line
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's only if you're not using OWIN.

Comment: @TravisIllig I downloaded and tested OP's sample project from GitHub. It works after I replace `config.DependencyResolver` with `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`.

Comment: If that's the case then the OP isn't using OWIN... or is trying to use both. Point being, the question currently says OWIN, so recommending anything be done with the GlobalConfiguration object is wrong. The answer is to fix the OP's code to use OWIN.

Comment: @TravisIllig Autofac using OWIN in non .Net Core project is also new to me. Thank you for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell WebApi how to create your controllers.  I like to do it by creating a composition root.  Mark Seemann has an excellent article on it [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/).  My implementation looks like this.  I am using StructureMap, but AutoFac will have a similar setup.  In the constructor, I am passing on the IoC container and in the `Create` method I get the instance of the controller out of the container using the `controllerType` parameter.

```
public class CompositionRoot : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public CompositionRoot(IContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller = (IHttpController) _container.GetInstance(controllerType);

        return controller;
    }
```

You wire it up in your startup.cs like this (again, using StructureMap):

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof (IHttpControllerActivator), new CompositionRoot(container));
```

This is a more manual wiring up, and it means that you probably won't need these lines:

```
app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You don't have to wire up a different controller activator - Web API 2 automatically tries to use the request scope to resolve the controller. [Here's the DefaultControllerActivator source.](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultHttpControllerActivator.cs) You _do_ need that `app.UseAutofacWebApi` call to ensure the request scope is available for the default controller activator to work.